# How to prevent UWP projects from restoring NuGet packages upon each Visual Studio session?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, uwp

For developing Universal Windows Applications in Visual Studio 2015, has anyone noticed that each time you launch a fresh VS session with your solution, the NuGet packages have to be restored as the first step of the build process? This is annoying when no changes have been made to the package configuration. So for instance if you just need to quickly restart VS and run your app, it has to go through this 20-second NuGet restoration which seems unnecessary.

Does anybody know how to achieve the same behavior as for a desktop application (i.e. it only restores NuGet packages if they are missing, etc)?

Comment: Please tag as answered. I did answer your question.

Comment: I have marked the other answer as answered. I already knew about turning off package-restore-on-build altogether, but I didn't want that option, I wanted the same behavior as for a WPF project (which does restore if packages are missing). Thanks for you input though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important question here is : *Do you want to cripple your development work (by disabling package restore during build as @user5525674 proposed) with the chances that something did change (e.g. in your source control) and doesn't get build correctly? Only to gain some seconds on the very first build of your Visual Studio session?*

There's a reason why it works 'as is'. You can read the full [documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/Consume/ProjectJson-Intro) on NuGet v3 and the build process, but this is the most important part in relation to the question:

> The restore process runs ahead of the build itself, it then writes out a new file called project.lock.json. The file includes the package graph as well as other useful information about the packages restored. MSBuild reads the file and translates it into a set of folders where potential references can be found, and then adds them to the project tree in memory.
>
> **Where is this file dropped** – Right next to the project.json
>
> **Should I check it in** – Typically no, the file is included in the default .gitignore in Visual Studio normally not included in source control either through .gitignore or .tfignore.

To recap:

- There is no more packages folder under your solution, downloaded packages are cached under your user's AppData directory.
- The file `project.lock.json` is generated by the restore process and holds the package references (this will fail your build if you disable the restore process under VS options and this file is missing or references are changed.
- The reference files/folders are kept **in memory** by MSBuild. A new VS sessions means that this tree has to be rebuild in memory and that's what takes your 20 seconds.

Comment: I understand your point Bart but the option is provided for the user to make. The user must understand the consequences of a chosen option and to assume a chosen option would cripple the development is a bit bordering on saying the user doesn't know what they're doing. I can temporarily use the option if that's to my advantage.

Comment: I'm just over-dramatizing the fact, because it's easily forgotten to re-enable. And that's when you'll loose a lot of time. But if the user read through my whole answer and understands how and why, he's free to do it anyway.

Comment: I was mainly wondering why the behavior seemed more "reasonable" in a classic desktop project. But from what you're saying it looks like the whole architecture is changed, and presumably, more advanced in a UWP project. It sounds like there are clear advantages to just suffering through those 20 seconds but keeping everything in sync. Thanks.

Comment: The point is really the new UWP development is becoming more reliant on the NuGet automation. As @Bart pointed out files such as project.json are new to Visual Studio 2015 for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, follow the **Tools** menu as below:

`Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager`

Then, **uncheck** the option:

`Automatically check for missing package during build in Visual Studio`

Comment: This will break your build after getting the code from source control.

Comment: I understand your point Bart but the option is provided for the user to make. The user must understand the consequences of a chosen option and to assume a chosen option would cripple the development is a bit bordering on saying the user doesn't know what they're doing. I can temporarily use the option if that's to my advantage.